# Unity app crash on first scene

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, unity-game-engine

I am receiving following log on unity app launch on Xcode.

```
2012-10-03 00:28:58.721 salah[1357:707] -> registered mono modules 0xe5d53c
-> applicationDidFinishLaunching()
Mono path[0] = '/var/mobile/Applications/6466AD40-4714-4F2A-A20F-5B6803CDC1ED/salah.app/Data/Managed'
Invalid serialized file version. File: "/var/mobile/Applications/6466AD40-4714-4F2A-A20F-5B6803CDC1ED/salah.app/Data/mainData". Expected version: 3.5.5f2. Actual version: 3.5.5f3.

(Filename: /Applications/buildAgent/work/14194e8ce88cdf47/Runtime/Serialize/SerializedFile.cpp Line: 709)

Failed to read file '/var/mobile/Applications/6466AD40-4714-4F2A-A20F-5B6803CDC1ED/salah.app/Data/mainData' because it is corrupted.

(Filename: /Applications/buildAgent/work/14194e8ce88cdf47/Runtime/Serialize/SerializedFile.cpp Line: 430)

PlayerInitEngineNoGraphics settings: Could not preload global game manager #0
   engine intialization failed
```

This causes my unity 3d app to crash before first scene comes forward.

Anybody knows workaround?

App have been switch alot with different versions of unity.

Comment: Have you tried a 'Reimport all' inside the Unity editor and then rebuilding?

Comment: That would require putting events in all animations again and hooking up all the Objects ... thats lots of work

Comment: Seems like something regarding your Unity versions is messed up on the device (3.5.5f2 /f3). I found that deleting the app helped me in most cases.

Comment: reinstallation of Unity 3.5.5f3 solved the issue. Now build is working fine on device as well.

Comment: Also I had to update my mac osx

Answer (score 3):

"No GlobalGameManagers file was found, quitting player!" happens, at least sometimes, because some random problem prevents the editor from going all the way to the end of the build.
Usually, you should be able to see an error in console that is not a compile error and could be easily missed if you clean the console.

In my case it was a windows dll "NSpec.dll" that I needed for my tests, but by mistake was not under an `Editor` path (and wasnot excluded from build, by the checkmark in the inspector) so during the build, Unity wanted to include it in my iOS build but then complained and stopped midway, while the half done project looked OK.

Answer (score 1):

You Should try to delete library and temp folder from the required folder which you have to build it from unity before opening at Xcode.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, this error happens (in VisualStudio) because I built the solution in Unity and debugged the same solution in VisualStudio at the same time, so the Unity build didn't run completely.

Answer (score 0):

Because of switching project from different unity versions that's occur. 
There is a folder in the Xcode project (open in finder) named "Data" you are using the latest one(f3) means unity replaced that Data folder with the latest unity version while app is expecting the old one "f2". So if you can copy and replace the "Data" folder from old project then this will solve the problem.

or updating the unity will also solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Any further solutions? replace the "Data" folder did not work for me..

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem and fix with [this.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31663393/2049325)

Project > Scheme > Edit > Run > Options > GPU Frame Capture > Disabled

[image]