# My app crashes when running on my iPhone, but not in the simulator. What are some debugging techniques I can use to reso the issue?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, debugging

The app crashes on the closing brace of `viewDidLoad` in the `GameViewController`. My `viewDidLoad` code looks like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let scene = GameScene(size: CGSize(width: 768, height: 1024))
    let skView = self.view as! SKView
    skView.showsFields = true
    skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
    skView.showsPhysics = true
    scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill
    skView.presentScene(scene)
  }
```

If I comment out the lines that create, scale, and present the `GameScene` then the app runs fine (it's essentially a blank view in this case). This tells me that there is obviously something going on in my `GameScene` class, but I cannot figure out exactly what.

When I run a backtrace, I get this:

```
    (lldb) bt
* thread #1: tid = 0x1d9f18, 0x00000001002d5bac libglInterpose.dylib`EAGLContext_renderbufferStorageFromDrawable(EAGLContext*, objc_selector*, unsigned long, id<EAGLDrawable>) + 180, queue = 'com.apple.spritekit.renderQueue', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x11f0)
    frame #0: 0x00000001002d5bac libglInterpose.dylib`EAGLContext_renderbufferStorageFromDrawable(EAGLContext*, objc_selector*, unsigned long, id<EAGLDrawable>) + 180
    frame #1: 0x0000000189252468 SpriteKit`-[SKView remakeFramebuffer:] + 600
    frame #2: 0x0000000189252e44 SpriteKit`-[SKView _setupContext] + 832
    frame #3: 0x0000000189253700 SpriteKit`-[SKView _renderContent] + 112
    frame #4: 0x00000001008a4f94 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_client_callout + 16
    frame #5: 0x00000001008af08c libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_barrier_sync_f_invoke + 128
    frame #6: 0x00000001892535a0 SpriteKit`-[SKView renderContent] + 100
    frame #7: 0x0000000189254d24 SpriteKit`-[SKView layoutSubviews] + 564
    frame #8: 0x00000001893dd760 UIKit`-[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 580
    frame #9: 0x0000000188d25e1c QuartzCore`-[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 152
    frame #10: 0x0000000188d20884 QuartzCore`CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 320
    frame #11: 0x0000000188d20728 QuartzCore`CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 32
    frame #12: 0x0000000188d1febc QuartzCore`CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 276
    frame #13: 0x0000000188d1fc3c QuartzCore`CA::Transaction::commit() + 528
    frame #14: 0x000000018966c838 UIKit`-[UIApplication _reportMainSceneUpdateFinished:] + 60
    frame #15: 0x000000018966d71c UIKit`-[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 2804
    frame #16: 0x000000018966b778 UIKit`-[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 184
    frame #17: 0x000000018d1a93c8 FrontBoardServices`__31-[FBSSerialQueue performAsync:]_block_invoke_2 + 32
    frame #18: 0x000000018495827c CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 20
    frame #19: 0x0000000184957384 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 312
    frame #20: 0x00000001849559a8 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 1756
    frame #21: 0x00000001848812d4 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 396
    frame #22: 0x000000018944c43c UIKit`-[UIApplication _run] + 552
    frame #23: 0x0000000189446fac UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 1488
  * frame #24: 0x0000000100046804 Ascii Attack`main + 164 at AppDelegate.swift:11
    frame #25: 0x000000019684aa08 libdyld.dylib`start + 4
(lldb)
```

But unfortunately I do not know where to go from here. I'm not really sure how to decipher the backtrace. I know that there is *something* wrong with my GameScene class, is there some way to figure out exactly what? Or do I have to test every property individually?

In addition to this, it turns out the app runs fine on my iPhone when I don't run the app in the debugger.

EDIT: The problem was resolved. It was apparently a bug with Xcode, not with any of my code. [EXC_BAD_ACCESS at lauch for EAGLContext renderbufferStorage: fromDrawable: in Cocos2d app whie debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31398961/exc-bad-access-at-lauch-for-eaglcontext-renderbufferstorage-fromdrawable-in-co/31483927#comment51270815_31483927)

Comment: I've seen similar things happening to people who have incorrectly included their resources in the project. The debugger can access files that aren't necessarily packaged and shipped to the phone. Perhaps a sprite sheet isn't properly included in the project?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Turns out it was a bug with xcode rather than any code, as seen in this question: [EXC_BAD_ACCESS at lauch for EAGLContext renderbufferStorage: fromDrawable: in Cocos2d app whie debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31398961/exc-bad-access-at-lauch-for-eaglcontext-renderbufferstorage-fromdrawable-in-co/31483927#comment51270815_31483927).

Apparently EAGLcontext_renderBufferStorage can cause errors on iOS 8.3+. The solution to this is to change the scheme that you are using to disable GPU Frame Capture. Not entirely sure why this works, but it does!